# Structuring Wireshark dissector to make filtering easier

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am writing my first Wireshark dissector. I am writing it in Lua, using [this as an example](https://mika-s.github.io/wireshark/lua/dissector/2017/11/04/creating-a-wireshark-dissector-in-lua-1.html). My communication protocol embeds a command ID in the response header, followed by well-defined payloads that differ based on the command ID. So far, I've been structuring the ProtoFields such that the Abbreviated name of the field (the string used in filters) follows a naming convention like this

```
proto_name.command_name.field_name
```

Some commands have similar fields, like in the following example

```
myproto.cmd_update.updateId
myproto.cmd_update_ack.updateId
```

where, per the protocol, an `update` command must be acknowledged with a `update_ack` command with the same `updateId` payload. Ideally, i would like to create a wireshark filter such that I can see all packets pertaining to the `updateId` field. I tried creating a filter like

```
myproto.*.updateId == 0x1234
```

but that appears to be invalid wireshark filter syntax. I don't want to make the filter explicit like

```
myproto.cmd_update.updateId == 0x1234 or myproto.cmd_update_ack.updateId == 0x1234
```

because in my actual protocol there are many more commands with similar/related fields. Is there a filter syntax I can use? Or perhaps, should I structure my dissector's ProtoField abbreviations differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a wildcard syntax for the filter line, so I wound up solving this in the dissector itself. In addition to the `myproto.*.updateId` fields, I also added another field called `myproto.updateId` (note the lack of the wildcard in the middle). Its value is set to the same thing as the full blown field name, which means that I now have just one field name to search against. I also set this field as `hidden = true` to hide it from view.

It's a bit of a hack, but gives me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a Wireshark [display filter macro](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChDisplayFilterMacrosSection.html).